# Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got ','

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

It's about Doctrine and the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function from the [Oro Doctrine Extensions](https://github.com/orocrm/doctrine-extensions) library.

Some code:

```
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $totalLogedTime  = $qb
                ->select('SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, ulr.logedIn, ulr.logedOut)) as sum')
                ->from('SDUserBundle:UserLoginRecord', 'ulr')
                ->where ...
```

config.yml

```
            dql:
                string_functions:
                    array_to_string: ITDoors\CommonBundle\DQL\ArrayToStringDQL
                    array: ITDoors\CommonBundle\DQL\ArrayDQL
                    select_next_handling_message_date: SD\CommonBundle\DQL\SelectNextHandlingMessageDateDQL
                    cast: Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\Cast
                datetime_functions:
                    date:  Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
                numeric_functions:
                    dayofyear: Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
                    year: Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
                    month: Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
                    day: Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
                    timestampdiff: Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
                    date: Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
```

Error:

```
    [Syntax Error] line 0, col 31: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got ','
```

DQL:

```
SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, ulr.logedIn, ulr.logedOut)) FROM SDUserBundle:UserLoginRecord ulr WHERE ulr.user_id = 353 AND ulr.logedIn > :start AND ulr.logedOut < :end
                               ^ - col 31
```

What's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: can you give us full DQL?

Comment: Run this `die($qb->getDql());` so we can see the full DQL or look in your profiler to get the full DQL. What the `select` function contains is not the same as what the resulting DQL may be

Comment: The DQL for the query, _not_ the full `dql` parameters from your `config.yml`

Comment: I have an error about to much code in post. What params you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `timestampdiff` configuration declaration is incorrect. You must use this parameter instead, [as per the README](https://github.com/orocrm/doctrine-extensions#symfony2):

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            numeric_functions:
                timestampdiff:  Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\Numeric\TimestampDiff
```

The reason the error message expects a closing `)` bracket is because the `SimpleFunction` is a one-parameter function and doesn't accept multiple arguments, so a `,` (comma) is never expected.

Comment: Thanks! Simple, as usual!)